# Windows Authentication for Xamarin UWP

Tags: windows, authentication, xamarin.forms

can any one help me how to do Windows Authentication using xamarin forms

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Reddy Krishna M

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at our documentation on using [Windows Integrated Auth](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively---Public-client-application-flows#properties-of-platformparameter-specific-to-winrt-and-uwp-corporate-network) with UWP. We also have a [sample app](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget) which demonstrates creating a Xamarin application that signs in users with AAD and calls the Microsoft Graph using OAuth 2.0 access tokens.

More documentation on [Integrated authentication on Windows](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos)).

For the authentication libraries, the implementation of WAM, which is another layer of Windows auth, is on the horizon. Hope this helps.